# Can I run MS Access with Ubuntu?

Tags: database

I do have Ubuntu but wondering if I can run MS Access on Linux? I really need it for college. I do have Windows 10 but I rather use Linux.

Does it work with Wine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’d recommend sticking to Windows as Microsoft Access is somewhat buggy on Ubuntu (at least from my experience).

Comment: Thank I will stick with Windows in that case. :)